# Initialize model - Swift 5

Tags: swift

I have the following model:

```
struct MyModel: Codable, Hashable {
    let name, chain_id, db_schema_name, label, logo_url: String?
    let is_testnet: Bool?
}
```

How can I initialize it with an empty value on a View?

I tried:

```
var myModel: MyModel? = MyModel()
```

but it throws an error:

```
Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call
Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'
```

How can I initialize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `let` to `var` throughout your declarations. A `let` Optional with no value is occupied by `nil` and cannot be set by the initializer. The compiler knows that, so it knows of no other viable initializer than the Decodable initializer.

Comment: wouldn't that be a security risk down the line? Is there another way?

Comment: Not if you want Optionals. I don't know what you mean by security anyway.